# How do use PHP file_get_contents or cURL with a log-in page that I'm already logged into

Tags: php, curl, cookies, web-scraping, file-get-contents

If I go to a website, example.com/page1.php, it is a log-in page.  When I log-in, it takes me to example.com/page2.php.  If I close my browser and come back to page1 later, I’m still logged in and it automatically takes me to page2.  That means there’s a cookie set and it knows I already logged in.
I want to use `file_get_contents` to get page2.php.  When I try it, I get the contents of the log-in page instead.  I assume that’s because `file_get_contents` doesn’t know a cookie is set and page2 is saying, you shouldn’t be here, you’re not logged in, so it bumps me back to page 1.
I realize I can use cURL to do the log-in, create a cookie and get the contents, like this….

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/page1.php'; // the url of the login page
$post_data = "urerid=myusername&password=mypassword ";  // The login data to post
$ch = curl_init(); // Create a curl object
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url ); // Set the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 ); // This is a POST query
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data); //Set the post data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Get the content
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // Follow Location redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); // Set cookie storing files
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
$output = curl_exec($ch); // Execute the action to login
```

My problem is , I don’t want to log-in again (for reasons I don’t want to get into).  Is there a way to let `file_get_contents`, cURL, or some other function, know I’m previously logged in and get the contents of page2.  Since example.com is setting a cookie, can I access that cookie somehow and use it to avoid logging in again?

Comment: Take the cookie from your browser and pass it to headers, either in curl or in `file_get_contentens` with `stream_context_create`.

Answer (score 0):

### Why it wont work:

1. If the website is creating security cookie against xss , you cant simply take one user cookies and send request from diffrent IP while using them.
2. Even if the website is not using security hash , **you cant access cookies belongs to a diffrent domain** due security resones (you dont want that gmail.com could access your microsoft.com cookies)

### to cut it short - the only way that could work is by :

1. Use SSO (with partner to the destination domain).
2. Use Cross-Domain support (with partner to the destination domain).
3. Get Access Tokens (like facebook is doing) if supported by the destination domain.
4. Request your users to login from your domain (by trusting you - which is bad) in order to let your site be able to access the other domain data.